# CMake: Different content in static and shared lib

Tags: python, cmake, static-libraries

Based on t[ensorflow lite minimal example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal), I build a small application and want to share it as lib.

My CmakeList looks like that:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(MY_LIB C CXX)

set(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR "" CACHE PATH
  "Directory that contains the TensorFlow project"
)
if(NOT TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR)
  get_filename_component(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR
    "~/tensorflow"
    # "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../"
    ABSOLUTE
  )
endif()

add_subdirectory(
  "${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite"
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../results)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../results)

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

add_library(MY_LIB SHARED
 src/my_code.cpp
)


target_link_libraries(MY_LIB
  tensorflow-lite
  ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
)

target_include_directories(MY_LIB PUBLIC
  inc
)
```

When running `build`, I get an .so file with ~ 5 MB, which works well even on machines without tensorflow (lite).

Then, I've replaced `add_library(MY_LIB SHARED`by `add_library(MY_LIB STATIC` and get the expected .a file. Surprisingly, this file has only 500 kB and lacks of symbols, when running it.

I assume that tensorflow content is part of shared lib, but referenced somehow externally in the static lib. What do I need to configure to get also the full code, without any external dependencies in the static lib?

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries) that both kinds of lib contains the whole code.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `set_property(TARGET MY_LIB PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)`

Comment: I've already set thia globally `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)`

Comment: "I've already set thi[s] globally"... **no, you haven't.** You set that variable _after_ including TFLite's sources via `add_subdirectory`.

Comment: "What do I need to configure to get also the full code, without any external dependencies in the static lib?" -- Does this answer your question? [Combining several static libraries into one using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake)

Comment: Even when setting the property (at the end of `CMakeLists.txt` nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that tensorflow content is part of shared lib, but referenced somehow externally in the static lib. What do I need to configure to get also the full code, without any external dependencies in the static lib?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441510/2137996)
[is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67432304/2137996)
[really](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976919/2137996)
[quite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26279476/2137996)
[hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4736442/2137996)
[to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60191548/2137996)
[do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50031940/2137996)
[in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63409763/2137996)
[CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14200728/2137996).<sup>1</sup>

If you're using CMake to manage your libraries, however, it isn't an issue since CMake will handle placing all the required static libraries in the correct order on the link line.

<sup>1. (Note: none of the linked answers, including mine, are correct in every possible scenario).</sup>

> I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649334/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries) that both kinds of lib contains the whole code.

That answer is a horrible oversimplification of what a static library is. A static library may have dependencies on other static libraries. CMake makes no attempt to *merge* static libraries together into one final artifact. On the other hand, linking a static library into a shared library *will* merge the two together.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a beginner I'll need much more time to read the linked questions and even more to understand the answers. Didn't expect that this is such a tough topic.